# How to get when MySQL instance went down last

Tags: mysql, linux, log

Is it possible to determine when a MySQL instance went down last? Is there a log file or literally anything at all that logs the server status in MySQL? I have trolled through countless articles online and have not found a single thing that offers any sort of help on this. HELP!

Comment: first do show variables like 'log_error' and it will display the error log being used by the instance and then from this file you can see the required information. hope it helps

Comment: so would the syntax be "mysql>show variable log_error"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that I came up with to get the information:

```
#!/bin/bash

######################
##BY: kixes         ##
##Created: 4-1-2016 ##
##Version: 1.01     ##
######################

#####################
######Variables######
#############################################################

#LogFile is where the ErrorLog dumps its filtered error log data
LogFile=/var/lib/mysql/admin/logs/shutdowns.log
#Error log holds the raw information from the MySQL Error log filtered by grep.
ErrorLog='grep 'Starting' /var/lib/mysql'`hostname`'.err'
#OutputFile holds a comma delimited set of values of hostname,shutdown date, shutdown time, startup time
OutputFile=/var/lib/mysql/admin/logs/shutdowns_`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`.csv

#############################################################
######Variables######
#####################

##################
######Header######
#############################################################

#Write (Not append) to $LogFile
$ErrorLog > $LogFile
#Writes (Not append) the table headers
echo "hostname,Shutdown_date,Shutdown_time,Startup_time" > $OutputFile

#############################################################
######Header######
##################

################
######Body######
#############################################################

#Do not change variables!
q=0
intholder=-1

#Go line by line in $LogFile. '$i' is the current line (string).
while read i; do
        ((q++))

        #If the line ($i) is a line containing shut-down information then gathers in shut-down information
        if [[ $i =~ "Starting shutdown..." ]]
        then
                shutdowndate=`echo "$i" | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}'`
                shutdowntime=`echo "$i" | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}'`
                ((intholder=$q + 1))
        fi

        #If the line ($i) is a line containing start-up information then gather that information
        if [[ "$intholder" == "$q" ]]
        then
                startuptime=`echo "$i" | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}:[[:digit:]]{2}'`
                echo "MySQL instance:`hostname` went down on $shutdowndate at $shutdowntime and started at $startuptime"

                echo "`hostname`,$shutdowndate,$shutdowntime,$startuptime" >> $OutputFile
        fi


#End loop
done <$LogFile

#############################################################
######Body######
################
```

Answer (score 1):

The file `mysql.log` shows startup and shutdown.

`SHOW VARIABLE LIKE 'log_error';` says where the file is.  However, also check `SHOW VARIABLE LIKE 'log_output';`.  (I don't know if *this* log is controlled by that.)

`SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Uptime';` says how many seconds it has been up.